# Pandas: Extract values from a column based on the values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

Now I have a list of indices `label_index`. I want to extract the corresponding values from a dataframe `label_file` based on the indices. The values of `label_index` will appear in column `image_num` in the dataframe and the goal is to get a list of corresponding values in `Thermal conductivity(W/mK)` column.

```
label_file = pd.read_excel("/Users/yixuansun/Documents/Research/ThermalConductiviy/Anisotropic/anisotropic_porous_media/data.xlsx",
                            sheet_name = "total")
label = []

for i in label_index:
    for j in range(len(label_file)):
        if i == label_file.iloc[j]["image_num"]:
            label.append(label_file.iloc[j]["Thermal conductivity(W/mK)"])
```

I used the brute force to find the match (two for loops). It does take a very long time to get through. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do so.

Comment: Sample data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get column "Thermal conductivity(W/mK)" where "image_num" column has one of the values specified in `label_index` list:

```
series = label_file.loc[
    label_file['image_num'].isin(label_index),
    'Thermal conductivity(W/mK)']
```

**EDIT 1:**
For sorting by `label_index` you can use an auxiliary column as following:

```
df = label_file.loc[
    label_file['image_num'].isin(label_index),
    ['Thermal conductivity(W/mK)', 'image_num']]
# create aux. column to sort by
df['sortbyme'] = df['image_num'].apply(lambda x: label_index.index(x))

# sort by aux. column and get only 'Thermal conductivity(W/mK)' column
series = df.sort_values('sortbyme').reset_index()['Thermal conductivity(W/mK)']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is much faster than before, but I realize this cannot assure it outputs in the same order. The values in `label_index` are not sorted. For example, if the indices are [3,1,2], I want it to output the corresponding thermal conductivity in the same order.  Is there a fast way to do that too? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a fast but cleaner way myself.

```
ther = []
for i in label_index:
    ther.append(label_file.loc[i]["Thermal conductivity(W/mK)"])
```

This will do the work.